# Layout best practices

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am new to Objective-C and developing a simple information app. Each screen simply links to another without any real programming for now. As I add new View Controllers for each screen, I realize I will have a large number of View Controllers for this app.

My question: Is this the best way to handle a simple app like this? There are 5 main sections, each section contains 3-5 sub sections, which would result in many View Controllers. I am thinking there is a simpler, cleaner way to maneuver text dynamically within one View Controller. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused a little bit as well. Good surviving!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tabBar controller with 5 tabs. In each tab there is a navigation controller that manages other view controllers of this section:

```
 myTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
  UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:name];
  UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];
......
  UIViewController *vc5 = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:name];
  UINavigationController *nav5 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc5];
  myTabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1,...,nav5, nil];
  [self.window addSubview:myTabBarController.view];
```

something like this...
p.s. sorry for bad formatting, hope you pick an idea.